# Getting 10 friends from friend-list problem in fbconnect problem

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

I am trying to fetch 10 friends list using fbconnect my query is like this,

```
NSString* fql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"select uid from user where uid == %lld LIMIT 1,10", _session.uid];

NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:fql forKey:@"query"];

[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.friends.get" params:params];
```

But it's fetching all the friends list, Anyone help me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSString* fql =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = %lld) LIMIT 1,10",_session.uid]; 

NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                fql, @"query",
                                nil];

[_facebook requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query" 
                       andParams: params
                   andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                     andDelegate: self];
```